# Ubuntu back to Windows XP with USB stick only

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, boot, usb

I installed Ubuntu on my HP nc4200 notebook . I now need to reinstall Windows XP on it . I want to run a Car Diagnostic programme that is only stable on windows XP. I have no CD/DVD drive on the machine so I have to boot from USB. I have tried creating a bootable usb stick using Wintoflash and a downloaded iso copy of XP but it will not load windows onto the notebook. It starts and comes to an error page. Can anyone help me please ? I need simple instructions that I can understand. I dont have a very good understanding of operating systems. I am in the South West of England if anyone can take a physical look.

Comment: What is the error / problem with the flash drive?

Comment: If you want it only for the Car Diagnostic program, you could be looking into using a Virtual Machine for that and stay with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can install a regular XP distribution from a USB stick. From what I recall, standard Win XP image does not have USB drivers installed, so after the BIOS finishes its initial job, the USB drive gets lost, and Windows installation can't proceed. You need to make a special Win XP ISO image to install it from USB, for the ideas [see this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20100926010118/http://www.ngine.de/index.jsp?pageid=4176).

Obviously, the least painful way is to simply buy/borrow an external USB CD/DVD reader.